# Blazor server SignalR disconnects when a component is included in both a razor page and a layout page

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have razor pages web application with a blazor component (menu) in the layout page. This works, but as soon as I add a razor page with a blazor component the components no longer respond. The errors I get in the browser console: [image]

Any help is appreciated.

[Example Application](https://github.com/ACertainDeveloper/BlazorIssue)

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for here. This is not a supported scenario. Blazor is Blazor and Razor Pages are Razor Pages. You can't use a Razor Component in a Razor page.

Comment: Yes you can. I currently have it working as long as I don't have a component in both the layout and razor page. Here is how you use a blazor component in a razor page: '''@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<MyComponent>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))''' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0#integrate-components-into-razor-pages-and-mvc-apps